# Add a filter on a query from multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets-filter

I have a multi-sheet google sheet that uses a query, and I want to filter down the sheet called Hugo to only Hugo on Column G and then do the same on the sheet called Vivian where I filter down on column G to Vivian only.  I cannot figure out how to add this filter so it works in real-time as new data is entered onto the other quered spreadsheets.

Here is a link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M3ssDpnhKTTGN321ICmT5a2MRJ80XdPZ6OxUkhQY9L0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an example of a formula for HUGO:

```
=QUERY({Idealease!A2:L;Retail!A2:L;Mobile!A2:L},"SELECT * WHERE Col1 is not null and Col7 = 'Hugo' order by Col12",0)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly.